# How to send an email with test report in Playwright?

Tags: angular, typescript, sendmail, playwright

I am new to develop web automation with playwright.As of now i create my test scenarios in playwright 1.16 version.its create the html file for after executing the test report.my question is how to add the send mail code into testMatch.because i try to add with testMatch:["first.test.ts","SendReportMail.ts"],but its executed parallel so here in this case SendReportMail.ts is execute before the first.test.ts.how to config the SendReportMail.ts after my test is finished then i wish to execute the SendReportMail.ts like in test ng have @AfterSuite i want to execute in playwright how can we do this for send mail to the stackholder.

Comment: You can try an put you code into https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test#test-after-all hook or https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testconfig#test-config-global-teardown but from what you describe it sounds more like a custom reporter which could be implemented using this api: https://playwright.dev/docs/next/test-reporters#custom-reporters

Comment: Yes...Thanks @ 
Yury Semikhatsky...Finally i add the node mailer mailing options and i implement the custom reporter addition in my code then the  mail we send with attached...the problem here is if we create html report own or we can place the playwright html files into the server then we can send the link then only we can see the view of the report.currently i will try to make own report for my concern.the one thing i seen in play wright 1.16 version added the html reporter and if with our expect is added the code does not create any report  its a good thing in playwright by default

Comment: @KarthiC , could you please add code snippet which you had tried, I am also trying to send an email using playwright.